# Electron loading html inside pre tag

Tags: angular, electron

I recently created an electron/angular app which runs the following inside `main.ts`:

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}));
```

When the electron app loads, the following shows [image: snapshot]
Somehow, the html is loading inside a `<pre>` tag inside html.
I have checked `__dirname/dist` and the folder contains all the correct files (i.e. index.html, main.js, etc). Has anyone seen something similar with electron before? If so, any clues as to what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not totally obvious, I fixed my issue - my `win` object was throwing warnings since I am using service workers and therefore, did not load the html properly.

The solution: use the `nodeIntegrationInWorker: true` property. Once that was added everything worked like magic.

```
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: Well done on finding your own answer :), If you have no further questions can you accept your own answer? (By clicking the tick below the voting buttons)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that sorry